# execCommand onMouseUp is not allowed in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am trying to auto copy the selection when user release their mouse. Yet, it seems like onMouseUp isn't recognised as user action, and executing execCommand is not allowed at the moment. (execCommand return false).

This will works:
mouse down > drag > mouse up, all complete within a second
(as onMouseDown is a valid user action I guess)

This will not works:
mouse down > drag for a while > mouse up

Here is the demo code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function mouseUp() {
                console.log(document.execCommand('copy'));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onmouseup="mouseUp()">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Returns true for me every time, even after dragging for 30s. I'm on 
Chrome 71.

Comment: Strange... tested in Chrome 72, both window and mac, return false when drag more than around 2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Browser_compatibility the copy function is deprecated (I couldn't find anything specific for Chrome.).

I achieved the same functionality with `navigator.clipboard.writeText()`.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function mouseUp() {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(window.getSelection()).then(function() 
                {
                    console.log("set");
                }, function() {
                     console.log("failed");
                });
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onmouseup="mouseUp()">
        <p>some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text some text <p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You may need to get permissions first as stated on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard#Using_the_Clipboard_API

> For page scripts, the Permissions API's "clipboard-write" permission is needed. You can check for that permission using navigator.permissions.query()